# Converse of sequence lemma on non metrizable spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

The following result is from Munkres : If X is a topological space with a subset $A$. If there is a sequence of points in $A$ converging to $x$, then $x \in \overline{A}$. Converse holds when $X$  metrizable.

I want to construct a counter example for the converse. That means I need a non metrizble space $X$ and its subset $A$ such that for some $x\in A$ there does not exist a sequence in $A$ which converging to $x$.

But when  $X= \{a,b,c \} $ with topology $ \tau = \{ \emptyset, \{a \},\{a,b \} ,\{a,c\}  X \} $ and $A= \{c \}$ Then $\overline{A}= \{c\} $ we can find  a sequence $(x_{n}) $ where $x_{n}=c$ which is in $A$ and converging to $c$.

I need a more natural counter example. Later Munkres use this lemma to show  $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ is non metrizable. I want a natural example like that

Comment: You probably mean $x\in \overline{A}$ in the first statement

Comment: A finite space cannot be a counterexample to this. The box product is a good example of it failing.

Comment: .Thanks I have made the correction. Munkres uses this lemma to show that  $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ with box product is not metrizable. So I cannot use it as a counter example. I want a space which I know is non metrizable where  lemma fails.

Comment: Look at the uncountable ordinal space $\bar{S}_\Omega$ defined on page 66.  Theorem 10.3 shows that any sequence in $S_\Omega$ would necessarily have an upper bound in $S_\Omega$, and therefore it could not converge to $\Omega$.  Yet $\Omega$ is in the closure of $S_\Omega$.